# Entity Framework Where method parameters

Tags: entity-framework-4, where-clause

The following EF statement does not compile as it is expecting 2 additional parameters, an int and a bool. I can't figure out how to supply them or what they are used for.

```
Dim L2 = Db.SecurityLogs.Where(Function(x) x.OrderId = OrderId)
```

The compile error is;

```
Error   27  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
'Public Function Where(predicate As String, ParamArray parameters() As System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter) As System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery(Of SecurityLog)': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of SecurityLog)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of SecurityLog)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Integer, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of SecurityLog)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of SecurityLog)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'.  D:\Projects\OutdoorAndCountry\trunk\Source\Server\DataModel\SecurityLogDb.vb    24  22  DataModel
```

I thought I understood how to use the Where method so I must be calling it differently to the way I normally do and MSDN only seems to refer to the passing of the function without parameters.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the last line in the compiler error message (which represents the relevant overload which should be applied) is the important hint:

> Extension method 'Public Function
>   Where(predicate As
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(Of SecurityLog, Boolean)))
>   As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of
>   SecurityLog)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Queryable': Option Strict
>   On disallows implicit conversions from
>   'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'.

It indicates that in your expression `x.OrderId = OrderId` either the left side (OrderId property of your SecurityLog class) is a nullable int (`Integer?`) or the type on the right side is a nullable int. Comparison of the a nullable and a non-nullable integer results in a nullable bool (`Boolean?`). The compiler complains that it cannot convert this `Boolean?` to the non-nullable `Boolean` which the lambda expression requires.

To solve the problem you could convert the possible `Nothing` value in the nullable type to `0` (or some other integer):

```
' If x.OrderId is the nullable Integer
Dim L2 = Db.SecurityLogs.Where(Function(x) If(x.OrderId, 0) = OrderId)
```

or

```
' If OrderId is the nullable Integer
Dim L2 = Db.SecurityLogs.Where(Function(x) x.OrderId = If(OrderId, 0))
```

(If not 100% sure about the VB syntax but `If(x, y)` should correspond here to `x ?? y` in C#, so: if x is Nothing then return y, otherwise return the value of x.)

You could also turn off the option **Strict On** in your VB compiler or project settings as this error only appears if the option is switched on. (But there might be some other reasons, I guess, to have this option on in your project, since it is non-default.)