# Why doesn't Entities-to-Linq in VB.NET like Lambda when Option Strict is ON?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Updated with new code:

I've got some very simple Linq using Entities

```
Return NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO.Where(Function(p) If(p.AssignedToUID, 0) = UserUID)
```

I can do that in C# without trouble by simple replacing `Function(p)` with `p =>`. But in VB.NET there's an added problem. If I try doing the above with Option Strict ON, then i get this massive compiler error.

I tried the solution suggested over at [Entity Framework Where method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633334/entity-framework-where-method-parameters) and changed my code to have the `If(p.AssignedToUID, 0)` but that gives me a very similar error.

Which is apparently some kind of casting error. I've seen several variations of people asking about this on this site and others, but none of the ones I found actually answer it: what do you have to do to make this work with Option Strict ON? I much prefer to work with it on.

Update:
Here's the error text:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
'Public Function Where(predicate As String, ParamArray parameters() As System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter) As System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO)': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Cannot infer a common type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO, Integer, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Cannot infer a common type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed.    C:\Programming\Sources\NDC\Custom Web Services\Mobile SAP WebServices\1.0.0.0\MobileSAPWebServices\MobileSAPWebServices\SAPMobileWS.asmx.vb 29  20  MobileSAPWebServices
```

Should I be `DirectCast`ing this to something?

Comment: Paste in the text of the error and code, the screen shot is tiny and we are all old.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Where method parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633334/entity-framework-where-method-parameters)

Comment: @asawyer Oh, that's a question I didn't find, let me see if that's it. Thanks!

Comment: A bit of squinting showed the actual error - conversion between bool? to bool is disallowed, google of `option string disallows boolean? to boolean` brought that up as the second hit, and it looks exactly like yours.

Comment: @Except that trying that doesn't fix my problem. Let me update my question

Comment: Doh! mouse over the two variables, one of them is sure to be nullable, probably `p.AssignedToUID`.

Comment: @asawyer Yea, I tried that, it seemed like the logical thing. But now Option Strict doesn't like something else about my code. I put the actual error text up this time.

Comment: @asawyer According to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92da4by7(v=vs.90).aspx I solve this problem either by setting Option Strict to Off, or by using `Is`. I really prefer the C# way of handling this..

Comment: I think Douglas has the right idea.

Comment: @asawyer I just tried Douglas' suggestion, but I'm still getting the same error. I need to play around with this more

Comment: What type is UserUID?  A Guid?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Yes, they're both Guids. Aha, that was it. `If(p.AssignedToUID, Guid.Empty)` was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: So it looks like these problems come down to whether the type is nullable in the database of not. That answers a lot of questions

Comment: Correct.  If you compare nullable to non-nullable, you get an indeterminate answer (`Boolean?` in this case)

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I learn something new every day. If you update your answer to have the Guid cast, I'll gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: Updated.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Though I wonder now. If I take out the DirectCast If stuff, but then change UserUID to be Guid? (nullable), I get that old error again. Shouldn't that also act as a solution?

Comment: No, because you are potentially comparing a null value with a Guid.  You need to coalesce the null into an empty guid.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Which I guess is a big nono. I wonder how C# is handling these under the hood

Comment: It worked in C# using zero?  If so, I am guessing that it cast both values to Object.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin But wait, what if I want to search for all of the rows that have that Guid as null, and I want to use a null Guid? to do it? Is that not allowed?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin No, I didn't need a 0 or anything. It just worked fine without any cast or If

Comment: Try this:  Return NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO.Where(Function(p) p.AssignedToUID.GetValueOrDefault = UserUID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my edit.

Try this:

```
Return NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO.Where(Function(p) If(p.AssignedToUID.HasValue, p.AssignedToUID.Value, 0) = UserUID)
```

think the issue might be that VB can't correctly infer that `p` is always going to be an `Integer` and instead guesses that it is nullable.  You can also try `DirectCast`, `Convert.ToInt32`, or `CInt` like so:

```
Return NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO.Where(Function(p) DirectCast(If(p.AssignedToUID, 0), Integer) = UserUID)
```

EDIT:  You are comparing Object to Guid, since `p` can evaluate to either a Guid or 0.  Change the zero to a Guid and you should be good to go.  Try this:

```
Return NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO.Where(Function(p) If(p.AssignedToUID, Guid.Empty) = UserUID)
```

OR

```
Return NDCEntity.tbl_Ext_Mobile_PO.Where(Function(p) If(p.AssignedToUID, Nothing) = UserUID)
```

Comment: I tried this already (just to note, AssignedToUID is a Guid, not Int), and what I'm getting now is a different error. Check the update to the question